# DataFrame - Values in column are dictionaries. How to keys and values to main data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have this df:

```
d = {'name':'CompanyABCD' , 
     'office_location':[{'office_x':'lat,long','office_y':'lat,long'}] , 
     'total_employees':100}

test = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

where test shows like:

```
    name          office_location                            total_employees
0   CompanyABCD   {'office_x': 'lat,long', 'office_y':...    100
```

How can I extract the information so the dataframe results in this:

```
    name          office_location                            total_employees  OfficeName  LatLong 
0   CompanyABCD   {'office_x': 'lat,long', 'office_y':...    100              office_x    lat,long
0   CompanyABCD   {'office_x': 'lat,long', 'office_y':...    100              office_y    lat,long
```

Comment: Is it an option to process the data *before* feeding the dataframe with it?

Comment: No. Its a given database

Comment: A dataframe and a database are different animals... Did you you just pick the wrong word or does the data come from a database?

Comment: the data comes from a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the dictionary to a dataframe and [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)  it  , then concat/assign to the dataframe after [`repeating`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) to the [`length`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) of the dictionary:

```
m = pd.DataFrame(test['office_location'].tolist())
           .melt(var_name='Office',value_name='LatLong')

out = (test.loc[test.index.repeat(test['office_location'].str.len())]
      .reset_index(drop=True).assign(**m))
```

---

```
          name                                   office_location  \
0  CompanyABCD  {'office_x': 'lat,long', 'office_y': 'lat,long'}   
1  CompanyABCD  {'office_x': 'lat,long', 'office_y': 'lat,long'}   

   total_employees    Office   LatLong  
0              100  office_x  lat,long  
1              100  office_y  lat,long
```

Comment: That worked! thank you! Did not know about melt method. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Here the simplest way is to extract the dictionnaries into a plain list of dictionnaries and build an auxilliary dataframe from that and concat it horizontaly to  the original one:

```
aux = pd.DataFrame(test['office_location'].tolist()).stack().reset_index(level=1)
```

At this point we have:

```
    level_1         0
0  office_x  lat,long
0  office_y  lat,long
```

Time to concat:

```
resul = pd.concat([test, aux.rename(columns={'level_1': 'OfficeName',
                 '0': 'LatLong'})], axis=1)
```

to get:

```
          name                                   office_location  total_employees OfficeName         0
0  CompanyABCD  {'office_x': 'lat,long', 'office_y': 'lat,long'}              100   office_x  lat,long
0  CompanyABCD  {'office_x': 'lat,long', 'office_y': 'lat,long'}              100   office_y  lat,long
```

But I think that you should pre-process the data when you extract it from the database and before feeding the dataframe with it.